# $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$ is divisible by at most $N$ primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, divisibility

Let, $\Pi_{n,m}= n(n+1) \cdots (n+m-1)$ and $P (m)$ denotes
greatest prime divisor of a positive integer $m$. For fixed $m$ and $t$, we will in fact consider the problem of classifying those positive
integers $n$ for which

$(2.1) \; \; P(\Pi_{n,m)} ≤ p_t$

where $p_t$ is the $t^{th}$ prime.

we will argue as follows. For
any given $m ≥ 3$, we will split $4 [m/4] $(or $ m − 1,$ if $m ≡ −1 \pmod 4$) of the indices
$0, · · · , m − 1$ into disjoint pairs of the form $(i,  i + 2)$, where $i ≡ 0, 1 \pmod 4$. There
are

$[\frac m4]+ [\frac {m+1}{4}]$ such pairs. Choose $t_0$ such that

$π(m − 1) ≤ t_0 ≤ t.$

If $m ≥ 3$, we can thus find an $i \in  [0, m − 3]$ such that the product $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$
is divisible by at most

$(2.2)\; \;  N= [\frac{t-t_0}{[\frac m4]+ [\frac {m+1}{4}]}]$

of the primes in

$(2.3) \; \;  \{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

The above excerpt is taken from ["PRIME FACTORS OF CONSECUTIVE INTEGERS by MARK BAUER AND MICHAEL A. BENNETT"](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/erdos-graham3.pdf).

**QUESTION:**
I am having trouble to understand $(2.2)$.

How the product $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$ is divisible by at most $ N=[ \frac{t-t_0}{[\frac m4]+ [\frac {m+1}{4}]}]$? Please write down the detail derivation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $S$ as
$$S:=\bigg\{(n+i)(n+i+2)\ |\ \text{$i$ is such that $i\in[0,m-3]$ and $i\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$}\bigg\}$$

Then, we have
$$|S|=\bigg[\frac m4\bigg]+\bigg[\frac {m+1}{4}\bigg]$$

We want to prove the following claim :

**Claim 1** : If $m ≥ 3$, we can find an $i \in  [0, m − 3]$ such that the product $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$ is divisible by at most $N=\bigg[\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg]$ of the primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

In order to prove Claim 1, it is sufficient to prove the following claim :

**Claim 2** : If $m ≥ 3$, we can find an $i$ satisfying $i \in  [0, m − 3]$ and $i\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ such that the product $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$ is divisible by at most $N=\bigg[\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg]$ of the primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

So, in the following, let us prove Claim 2.

*Proof of Claim 2* :

Assume to the contrary that for every $i$ satisfying $i \in  [0, m − 3]$ and $i\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$, the product $(n + i)(n + i + 2)$ is divisible by at least $\bigg(\bigg[\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg]+1\bigg)$ of the primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

Now, let us use the following lemma (a proof of the lemma is written at the end of this answer) :

**Lemma** : For every prime $P$ in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$, the number of the elements of $S$ divisible by $P$ is at most $1$.

Now, consider the product of all the elements of $S$.

It follows from lemma 1 that the product of all the elements of $S$ is divisible at least by$$|S|\bigg(\bigg[\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg]+1\bigg)\tag1$$
of the primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

Here, $(1)$ is bigger than $t-t_0$ since, using $[x]\gt x-1$, we have
$$|S|\bigg(\bigg[\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg]+1\bigg)\gt |S|\bigg(\frac{t-t_0}{|S|}\bigg)=t-t_0$$

This implies that there have to exist more than $t-t_0$ primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.

This contradicts that there are $t-t_0$ primes in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

Finally, let us prove the lemma :

**Lemma** : For every prime $P$ in $\{ p_{t_0+1}, · · · ,p_t\}$, the number of the elements of $S$ divisible by $P$ is at most $1$.

*Proof of Lemma* : Assume to the contrary that there are two non-negative integers $i,j$ such that $i,j\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ and $0\le i\lt j\le m-3$ and $0\equiv (n+i)(n+i+2)\equiv (n+j)(n+j+2)\pmod P$.

- If $n+i\equiv n+j\equiv 0\pmod P$, then we get $j-i\equiv 0\pmod P$ which is impossible since $1\le j-i\le m-3\lt m-1\lt P$.
- If $n+i\equiv n+j+2\equiv 0\pmod P$, then we get $j+2-i\equiv 0\pmod P$ which is impossible since $3\le j+2-i\le m-1\lt P$.
- If $n+i+2\equiv n+j+2\equiv 0\pmod P$, then we get $j-i\equiv 0\pmod P$ which is impossible since $1\le j-i\le m-3\lt m-1\lt P$.
- If $n+i+2\equiv n+j\equiv 0\pmod P$, then we get $j-i-2\equiv 0\pmod P$. Since $-1\le j-i-2\lt m-1\lt P$, we have to have $j=i+2$. Since $i\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$, we have $j\equiv 2,3\pmod 4$ which contradicts that $j\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer, could u plz tel why we have to have $j=i+2$ ? Also if possible please upvote my post, because of serial down-vote i can't post anymore, there is no other way to solve this ban, thanks.